# Print webpage not shown some images and some background color im webpage

Tags: c#, javascript, printing

I code for printing the webpage.I am printing the webpage using javascript and the code is like

```
function print()
{
      window.print();
}
```

I call this function in onclientclick of Button.but when i see the print it doesnt show me some of images and background color.It doestnot happen with all.It shows me some of images and some of images are missing.same with background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely Internet Explorer's own setting.

In IE8 and earlier, there's a setting under Tools.Internet Options, Advanced tab, Printing section, which controls if background images and colours are printed.

In IE9, it's now a setting in the File.Page Setup... dialog options.

Comment: Image tags are always printed, background images via CSS are not (depending on that setting), so always use actual image tags if you need the image to be printed 100% of the time.